# Regarding Web application recommendation

Tags: support, allowed-topics

Is it on-topic here on in the main site to request for web application meeting a certain criteria?

Example question:

*Web application that allows one to search for {country} stocks based on minimum difference between **today's low** and **52 weeks low***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the reason for closing such a question -

[image]

The type of question is specificaly considered off-topic.